# Ограничение количества запросов от 1 Useragent(-а)

Tags: nginx

Требуется ограничить количество запросов от 1 Useragent(-а).
Как лучше всего сделать это на nginx?

Например: От 1 Useragent(-a) запросов не более чем N

(В целях борьбы с DDos-атаками)

Comment: Никак ибо это не поможет в борьбе с DDos

Comment: У меня в логах около 50 000 различных ip адресов, но у всех один и тот же useragent. Я бы мог добавить его в firewall, но я считаю более разумным ограничить число запросов.

Comment: Вы считаете это DDos'ом? почему? не может быть у 50к пользователей одного и того же браузера? или вы думаете если это DDos то для тех кто его генерирует составит проблему сменить UserAgent ?

Comment: Я защищаю себя постепенно, различными фильтрами. Да это Ддос атака, т.к 50к пользователей с одним и тем же юзерагентом за 10-15 минут это не нормально. 
Если я добавлю просто в firewall этот юзерагент, то ДДосер сменит его. Но по какой то причине он не генерирует их случайным образом, а использует 1. Означает что если я ограничу кол-во запросов с 1 юзер агента, то как минимум он навредить уже не сможет

Comment: Он их не "генерирует" потому что ему в данный момент это не нужно, еще раз то что написано в первом комментарии - это не защита от DDos атак, **это создание проблем легитимным пользователям**, Почитайте хоть не много по теме защиты от разных видов DDos атак, перед тем как делать бездумные бесполезные вещи.

Comment: Это создаст проблему, только конкретным легитимным пользователям с таким же Useragent(-ом) как и у атакующих ботов. В ином же случае, я получаю полностью не работающий сайт на время Ддос атаки.
Я развиваюсь только в этой теме, и обязательно найду решение по лучше когда найду его.
Сейчас мне нужно конкретно это.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88515/discussion-between---and-it-masxter).

Comment: `fail2ban` - читает лог и при наступлении определенных условий выполняет определенные действия. 

Но мне кажется лучше защититься через куки. Сделать CSRF на все запросы, требующие вычислений. Для запросов без спец кук сделать страничку "подождите, мы проверим что вы не робот".